# Can you use a primary key INT in a table to reference another Table Name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Basically I have a first table that has some simple info that can be stored in one column, and the second table is a large 2-D array.

Each column in my first table corresponds to all of the data in 2-D array, so since I don't want to repeat the first table info for every row in the second table, I want to create a primary key to link the two tables.

Since all data in my second table corresponds to my first, it would be great if I can use the Table Name itself instead of any values to link the two tables.

Is this possible? I've only ever seen foreign key values correspond with primary keys in another table.

Comment: That's a polymorphic association, so no, MySQL doesn't support foreign keys on that.

Comment: Thanks. Could you recommend a scalable database that supports polymorphic associations?

Comment: MySQL doesn't require that a foreign key correspond to a primary key, but it's the most common way to use them.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're doing. Can you show some example data, and explain the relationships?

Comment: What do you mean by using the table name to link the two tables? Aren't the table names known, not variable? Did you mean the column name?

Comment: @Barmar I did mean the table name. I want an entire table (all rows and columns) correspond to one column in my first table

Comment: Then why do you need to enter it anywhere? Just use the name of the second table in your queries.

Comment: Or is it possible to have just one value in a column? While all other columns might have hundreds of values. This would mean I would create a new table (from a prototype) every new dataset instead of adding columns to an existing table. Is this possible then?

Comment: @Barmar my problem is that I have a 2-D array of values that I need to link with 4 different indicators like Notes, Time, etc...

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't require that a foreign key refer to a primary key, it doesn't even have to be a unique key. It only has to have an index. So your second table can have a non-unique `array_id` column for each row of the 2-D array, and the first table can have foreign keys to this.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    notes INT,
    time INT,
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT (notes) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES table2 (array_id),
    CONSTRAINT (time) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES table2 (array_id),
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    array_id INT,
    row INT,
    column INT,
    value INT
    PRIMARY KEY (array_id, row, col)
);
```

So if you want to get the `notes` array related to a particular row in `table1`, you can do:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.notes = t2.array_id
WHERE t1.id = @id
```

Comment: I don't believe this helps, sorry. I don't want to join the tables at all. You can think of the first table as a list of measurements, let's say it has 1 column of Measurement ID. My 2nd table is a 2-D array of the actual measurement values. Can I create new tables using a template, and name each table as the Measurement ID from the 1st table?

Comment: I asked you to show some sample data and how it's being used. You didn't, so I tried to figure out what you're doing. If you want a better answer, post a better question.

Comment: Are you talking about having lots of different table 2's, one for each 2-D array? That's poor design. Just put it all in one table, with an ID like I show to refer to the specific array that you want.

Comment: A general rule of relational database design: anything that varies dynamically should be in table data, not table and column names.

Comment: Sorry my initial question is apparently impossible because of polymorphic association. And yes I would want a new table for each 2-D array, because they may be different length. (a 0.5 second measurement vs. a 5 second measurement)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I was thinking it was always 2 columns in the array. See my new `table2`, where there are separate `row` and `column` columns. This allows you to store arbitrary size arrays. But it's still one table for all arrays, using `array_id` to distinguish them.

Comment: I think I could use that methodology for my application. Thanks! Will return here after I try it out. I'm new to MySQL so it may take a while

Comment: Sometimes it's tricky to think relationally, and translating traditional data structures to relational tables can be non-intuititive.